# How to find the average of highest three inputted numbers

Tags: python-3.7

The goal here is to try and find the average of the three highest inputted grades, when four numbers are put in. I think I've come close but I'm running into a syntax error and I can't seem to find what is causing it.

I've got almost no experience with python so excuse the sloppy code but this is what I've gotten so far.

```py
def highestThreeAvg(grade1 : float, grade2 : float, grade3 : float, grade4 : float) -> float:
    """Given the grades, grade1, grade 2, grade3, grade4, returns the average
    of the three highest grades"""
    return (((grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) - lowestGrade) / 3

grade1 = float(input("Enter first grade: "))
grade2 = float(input("Enter second grade: "))
grade3 = float(input("Enter third grade: "))
grade4 = float(input("Enter fourth grade: "))

def lowest(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4):
    if (grade1 < grade2) and (grade1 < grade3) and (grade1 < grade4):
        lowestGrade = grade1
    elif (grade2 < grade1) and (grade2 < grade3) and (grade2 < grade4):
        lowestGrade = grade2
    elif (grade3 < grade1) and (grade3 <grade2) and (grade3 < grade4):
        lowestGrade = grade3
    else:
        lowestGrade = grade4
    print(lowestGrade)
lowest(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4)

print(highestThreeAvg)
```

The syntax error that I'm running into is at the start of line 6

```
grade1 = float(input("Enter first grade: "))
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you see any other issues with my code or where I can improve it feel free to let me know.

Comment: `lowest` already exists; it's called `min`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing an additional close bracket, as shown below, at the end of line 4 should solve the syntax issue.

```
return (((grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) - lowestGrade) / 3)
```

Comment: Or alternatively, better yet, remove the first one as the outer brackets have no effect

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have 3 `(`, but only 2 `)` in the previous line !